# Should I be adding alt and title for WordPress images on multilingual sites

Tags: wordpress, image, seo, alt

I am building a multilingual Wordpress website and I am using YoastSEO plugin.

I am missing alt and title attributes on my images, but I'm not sure if I should add them, since I'll have at least three languages? Maybe add them in English?

Any tips?

Best regards!

Comment: add them in your primary language....in practical terms its extremely hard to get SEO performance in multilanguage with one version of the site, try subdomains, a language uri etc, you will need to redo images in the language you want to target.

Answer (score 1):

The `title` tag is outdated. You just need to add an alt in English.

Google will translate your image's `alt` tags. You can Google "سیب" and see images without "سیب" in `alt` but have "apple" in their `alt` tags.

Comment: The `title` tag isn't exclusive to `img` tag; It is used to add Tooltips to HTML elements.

Answer (score 0):

Alt tags are required for valid HTML markup. More detail at [docs.webplatform.org](https://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/html/attributes/alt). What you could do is use *alt* attributes the [16 word](http://www.hobo-web.co.uk/how-many-words-in-alt-text-for-google-yahoo-bing/) limit to add multiple language. e.g.

```
<img src="img/cake.jpg" alt="[:en]Cake[:de]Kuchen[:]">
```

There is also a WordPress plugin called [qTranslate X](https://wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate-x/) which allows for dynamic multilingual text replacement at the front-end using this format.

Otherwise your other option is to do as @David suggests above and serve up multiple versions of your site.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Additionally just found this plugin to make qTranslate and YoastSEO play nicely together: [Yoast SEO & qTranslate-X](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-seo-qtranslate-x/)